# API rate limiting issue when requesting via PHP curl

Tags: php, api, curl, rate-limiting

My site integrates with another site via their API which was designed for their UI (a vuejs app).
I have permission to integrate with their API however they offer no technical support and I am running into issues.

It seems that when I make requests from my backend (supporting my own UI) using PHP and curl I often hit what seems to be API limiters.
For eg API calls will work but it they happen too close in succession I then get a long running request which eventually gets rejected via timeout with a an error of cant connect to server.

However if I test via their vuejs UI even multiple successive API calls do not seem to ever hit this limitation.

Given that all the API calls whether from my local PHP curl app or from the browser using their vuejs app are originating from my IP and I can't understand how there could be a distinction between the VueJs api calls which are not being limited and my PHP curl requests which are being limited.

Can anyone provide any insight as to why this could happen and if there is any way that I can get my curl php service to have the same behaviour as the browser requests which don't encounter these limits.

Thanks

--- Update----

Spoke to the API owners and nothing is blocking from their end. What I noticed is that if i have a long running ping while making the request I don't get any timeouts. But I dont really know what that means, ie how that is helping?

Comment: Check the headers that the vuejs app is sending when it makes a request in the Network Tab. You should replicate all of the parameters using PHP curl.

Comment: yes tried that. I will double check but pretty sure I am setting everything the same. Is there anything else that could distinguish the two requests?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Make positive that the headers are identical.

Comment: It's your app that makes the call and authenticates itself, usually by a token and/or secret that only lets your app make connections. So, IPs aren't the only consideration. Also, even if they don't offer tech support, you should still have an area where you can report bugs with their API, if that's what's going on. Finally, the first thing you should try is to eliminate your PHP code as the problem by manually making the request with an API client like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/product/api-client/), and checking if you still have the problem then.

Comment: Thanks for sending some details. I have the same issue with Postman - every request or two will get "blocked". I captured all the headers of the browser requests in Fiddler and used exactly the same headers in my Postman requests. So something else is applying limiting to my "manual" requests as opposed to the browser requests. I even "replayed" the login request from the browser multiple times (via fiddler) and had no issues. I cant figure out what the distinction is!!

Comment: It probably varies by operating system (Windows, Ubuntu, Debian, MacOS, whatever) but the default user agent sent by a curl request might be empty or something like **PHP** rather than the user agent string of a browser. Consider something like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0");`. This might also be due to some kind of *keep-alive* behavior of curl or something.

Comment: Thanks. I was already setting the user-agent. I have also tried change the Connection header - Closed or Keep-Alive. No difference.